# how the interval function update seconds would effect minutes?

Tags: javascript, date

If use integer counter, that should be easier by mod 60, but there is some problem with Date() object.

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date();
var timeCounter = 50;
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
setInterval(function(){
    d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    timeCounter++;
}, 1000);
</script>
```

After the interval function, the minutes would count following the seconds; which is fine. But when the counter change, the minutes would go up the same time as seconds, such as "1:01", "2:02", "3:03"...

but when I simply use the getMinutes function repeatedly, the function works normal

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getMinutes());  //12
console.log(d.getMinutes());  //12
console.log(d.getMinutes());  //12
```

The question how the interval function update seconds would effect minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the initial time is `00:00:00`.

You set the seconds to `50` and it becomes `00:00:00`.

You then set the seconds to `65` and it tries to become `00:00:65`, but that isn't valid, so the extra minute of seconds gets added to the minutes: `00:01:15`

Now the time is `00:01:15`

If you change the seconds to `30` it would become `00:01:30`. You are changing the **seconds** of the currently set time, not the time that was set when you first created the object.

So the time is `00:01:30`.

If you change the seconds to `65` we get `00:01:65`, which is invalid so the extra minute of seconds gets **added to the minutes that are already there**. `1 + 60/60 = 2` so you get: `00:02:15`

---

If you want to take this approach, then I'd suggest using the Moment library. It has nice APIs for dealing with adding time and cloning the object.

```js
var start = moment();
start.minute(0);
start.second(0);
var timeCounter = 50;

setInterval(function() {
  // Clone the original object so we aren't adding from the previous value
  var now = moment(start);
  now.seconds(timeCounter);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = now.format("mm:ss");
  timeCounter++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

---

That isn't a great approach though. The precision of `setInterval` isn't great and it can get delayed for multiple seconds under some circumstances.

You are better off starting with a time, and then calculating the difference between then and now each time you update the display.

```js
var start = moment();

setInterval(function() {
  // Clone the original object so we aren't adding from the previous value
  var now = moment();
  var dur = moment.duration(now.diff(start)); 
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dur.minutes() + ":" + dur.seconds();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

reset `timeCounter` after one minute:

```
var d = new Date();
var timeCounter = 50;
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
setInterval(function(){
    d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    timeCounter++;
    if(timeCounter === 60)
    {
        timeCounter=0;
      d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 1);
    }

}, 1000);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyg8vd9h/)

Answer (score 0):

When you reach a 60 second count, you have to increase the minutes and reset the seconds.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var d = new Date();
var timeCounter = 55;
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("minutes: " + d.getMinutes(), "seconds " + d.getSeconds());
    if(timeCounter === 60) {
      d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 1);
      timeCounter -= 60;
    }
    d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
    output.textContent = fixDigit(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + fixDigit(d.getSeconds());
    timeCounter++;
}, 1000);

function fixDigit(d){
 return (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `d.setSeconds(65)` will increase minutes by one and change seconds to 5. So in every
iteration with `timeCounter > 59` you will increment minutes as well.

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds):

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range,
>   setSeconds() attempts to update the date information in the Date
>   object accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the
>   minutes stored in the Date object will be incremented by 1, and 40
>   will be used for seconds.

If you want to implement a simple counter use:

```
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are starting from 50 seconds and incrementing seconds for iteration
2. As seconds reach 59,it gets to 60,which is 1:00
3. Try setting timeCount to 50 once it reached to 59 and increment minutes at this would fix it

change your code snippet to the following

```js
var d = new Date();
var timeCounter = 50;
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
setInterval(function() {
  d.setSeconds(timeCounter);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
  //alert(timeCounter);
  if (timeCounter == 59) {
    var minutes = +d.getMinutes();

    minutes += 1;
    //alert(minutes);
    d.setMinutes(minutes);
    timeCounter = 50;
  } else
    timeCounter++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Hope this helps